# How all value_counts in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to get all value count in dataframe, so wrote this

```
counter = df.value_counts();
print(counter);
```

I expected this style

```
100.0   4
25.0    7
0.0     2
    .
    .
```

but it show me this, not value count.

```
Series([], dtype:int64)
```

What should I do to get value that I expected?

Comment: Could you please provide input details and expectation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can flatten the dataframe values and convert it to Series

```py
out = pd.Series(df.values.flatten()).value_counts()
```

Comment: That's exactly I wanted! Thank you :)